# Why can't I access Jenkins URLs from within a Jenkins groovy script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plugin and the Jenkins SSH credentials plugin and would like to use them together so that I can have groovy code that auto-populates a choice parameter with the ssh systems I have configured (or a subset more likely) and allows me to pick which system I want to run a deployment to.  I've found a URL that provides the list of ssh hosts and have this basic code already written:

```
def myURL="http://myJenkins/job/myJob/descriptorByName/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHBuilder/fillSiteNameItems"
def allText=new URL(myURL).getText()
```

I've verified the URL does return JSON with the list of connections when I hit it from anywhere outside of Jenkins (REST client, wget, and even groovysh), but when I try to call it inside the dynamic parameter groovy code, I keep getting:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:369)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230
        ...
```

So I'm wondering if this is some sort of threading issue (the thread that is running this is maybe the same thread that would respond to the http request), but my knowledge of Jenkins at a programming level is somewhat limited.  If anyone can point me to how to get what I'm after (maybe even in a simpler way), I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: what happens if you test this URL using cURL from inside the machine running Jenkins? Have you tried using localhost instead of myJenkins?

Comment: @drorb I've tried localhost with the same result (actually localhost:8080 since that is the port I'm using).  Not sure why curl would be different than wget, but I tried it also and correctly got the content.  The ONLY place it hasn't worked was within Jenkins.

Comment: cURL is less important, the focus was on sending the request from within the same machine. If Jenkins is listening on port 8080, you do need it in the URL being used your Groovy code

Comment: is your Jenkins agent running on the same machine as your server?

Comment: I've tried every variation of the URL I can think of, with and without the port number, with the hostname and localhost.  I've "anonamized" the URL here since I know it's not the issue and to not draw attention to the machine.  I believe this part of the job will always run on the Jenkins server since the groovy code is actually run before I run the job, when I go to the "build with parameters" page.

Comment: I know this question ist quite old, but... do you have a proxy configured?